# actions must be a plane object Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, web, redux, middleware

I am writing a function to add an item to a cart. If the item does not exist in the cart, it should create a new cart item with a quantity of 1. If it already exists, it should increment the quantity. However, I am getting an error despite the function updating/adding the item to Firebase. The function code is shown below:

```js
function addToCart(item) {
  const cartRef = db.collection("cart").doc(user.uid);
  cartRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      const cartItem = doc.data()[item.id];
      if (cartItem) {
        cartRef.update({
          [`${item.id}.quantity`]: cartItem.quantity + 1,
        });
      } else {
        cartRef.update({ [item.id]: { ...item, quantity: 1 } });
      }
    } else {
      cartRef.set({ [item.id]: { ...item, quantity: 1 } });
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error updating cart:", error);
  });
}
```

I also updated my react store (shown below) with react-THUNK as suggested by chat GPT, but even after trying to print something inside it, the function still isn't working:

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the function isn't working correctly?

Comment: Which action do you dispatch throw this error?